# Laravel Form Request unique field validation on update

Tags: laravel

I have to make Form Request and have a unique rule on the title. How to ignore unique validation for updating id?

These are my rules when I try to get an id passed from the controller.

```
public function rules()
{
        $id = $this->request->get('id') ? ',.' $this->request->get('id') : '';
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required|min:3|unique:parent_categories',
        ];
        if ($this->getMethod() == 'PUT' || $this->getMethod() == 'PATCH') {
            $rules += ['title' => 'required|min:3|unique:parent_categories,title' . $id];
        }

        return $rules;

}
```

This is my controller where I am trying to update content with id.

```
public function update(ParentCategoryRequest $request, $id)
{

        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $parentCategory = ParentCategory::update($id, $request->all());
            DB::commit();
            return $this->success('Parent category updated successfully', new ParentCategoryResource($parentCategory), 201);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
        }
}
```

I am getting...

> undefined variable $id on ParentCategoryRequest

Comment: Can you please share codes as text?